# ANE C API - Converting uint8_t String to MFC virtual key code

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, mfc, air

First, I apologize in an advance as this may be a bit of a vague question since as of now I don't have all too much to go off of.

I'm in the process of writing an ANE that takes an AS3 String and passes it off to a MFC C++ dll that inputs it to Windows using `SendInput`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Now I'm not yet too familiar with the Flash C API but I'm currently under the impression that Strings passed over from AS3 are typed as `const uint8_t` on the C side and populated using `FREGetObjectAsUTF8`. I'm using the following code to accomplish this:

```
uint32_t len;
cost uint8_t str;
FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str); //string is a single char
```

To send the keystroke I'm using this

```
void KeyboardHelper::sendKeyStroke(int vk){
    INPUT input = {0};
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = 0; //not scanning for hardware key
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    //virtual key code for the key we want to press
    input.ki.wVk = vk;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0; //keypress
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
}
```

`input.ki.wVk` is looking for the hex value of the keycode to be sent. MSDN has a list of all the hex values and associated keystrokes here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This code does work and I am able to input a keystroke from my AIR app its just not the correct key. Since you can convert `uint8_t` to `int` my current incorrect code is calling `sendKeyStroke` like this:

```
FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str); //line from above
keyboardHelper->sendKeyStroke(int(str));
```

Again, this does seem to work, but I just get a random input.

I'm also not really even sure what the value of `str` or `int(str)` are since I haven't figured out how to step into this code when its being called from AIR. As a side-note, if anyone knows anything about debugging ANE's feel free to let me know :) (I'm using VS2012)

**I guess the root of this question comes down to this:**

Is it possible to convert a `const uint8_t` to a corresponding virtual key code? In this case I will only be dealing with one keystroke at a time.

If not it also seems like `KEYBDINPUT wScan` takes a unicode character if `dwFlags` is set to `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`. Would it be possible to convert `const uint8_t` to a `WORD` type I could use in `wScan`?

I've been using the following MSDN docs as reference:

KEYBDINPUT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

SendInput: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function suggests, the string is encoded as UTF-8 (Unicode) with uint8_t used to represent a byte. In order to interface with the MFC, you should convert that string to a UTF-16 (also Unicode) string. For that, the win32 API and also MFC use WCHAR as unit for each 16-bit word. You can use `MultibyteToWideChar()` function to achieve that, maybe more recent MFC versions also have helpers for that, I'm confident you'll find those.

Now, concerning the conversion to a virtual keycode, I'm afraid you're out of luck. In particular, Unicode doesn't provide ways to represent cursor keys, shift, control etc, hence the UTF-8 string won't contain any of these. It might be enough to send the characters of the string in separate keypresses though.

One more note:

```
uint32_t len;
cost uint8_t str;
FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str); //string is a single char
```

Check the docs, but I'd bet that the `&len` parameter is input and output! As input, it should receive the length of the buffer pointed to by `&str`. The way you're using it, you could have buffer overflows.